# No exported types in UMD module using WebPack, Babel and ES2015

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have problems with WebPack and exported classes using UMD module library. The problem is that when I try to load packed bundle into browser, then the exported object is empty (there are no properties that would match exported objects).

I created simple testing project for this:

*Project structure*

```
~/Playground/webpack-exports-test tree -I node_modules
.
├── build
│   ├── test.html
│   ├── testlib.js
│   └── testlib.js.map
├── bundle.js
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── a.js
│   └── b.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
let path = require('path');
let libraryName = 'testlib';
let bundleName = libraryName + '.js';

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './bundle.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: bundleName,
        library: libraryName,
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

*package.json*

```
{
    "name": "webpack-exports-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
        "webpack": "^1.13.3"
    }

}
```

*src/a.js*

```
export class A {
}
```

*src/b.js*

```
import {A} from './a.js'

export class B extends A {
}
```

*bundle.js*

```
import {A} from './src/a.js'
import {B} from './src/b.js'
```

When I tried debugging the code generated by WebPack then it seems that class objects are properly created, passed to `exports` but nothing is returned to global object.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to that. The problem was that entry `bundle.js` was not exporting any symbol.

This makes it work

```
import {A} from './src/a.js'
import {B} from './src/b.js'
export {A as A}
export {B as B}
```